# How can I add a menu link on the right side of my menu bar while having the main menu on the left side?

Tags: routes

I have a menu bar displaying the main menu on the left side and I would like to add a link to user account on the right side (right corner). I am using the TB mega menu module. Any idea of how I could do that? Thanks!

EDIT: here is a screenshot showing the main menu I was referring to (Home - Resources - Development Hub - Community Center). What I would like to do is to add the user menu (using the TB mega menu module) on the other side of the menu bar (right side).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This isn't really Drupal specific; I believe you just need to use CSS to solve it.

Comment: You're probably right, but it could be Drupal specific if the answer implies the use of a particular function provided by the TB mega menu module. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really figure out what you want, exactly. Could you maybe post a screenshot of what you have and a mockup of what you are trying to achieve? My English isn't that great, and one image is worth a thousands words. Maybe it is a CSS issue, maybe not really, can't tell now.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity... Don't hesitate to tell me if this type of question is not relevant for this forum and we'll leave it here. Otherwise, any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: is the main menu a block? if not can you change to a block?

Comment: @Aboodred1 the main menu is a block

Comment: It's easily solvable by assigning both the main and user menus to the same region, user menu needs to have a lower weight (above main menu), float the user menu to the right. Style the region as having grey background and borders.